# Copy range from master sheet from all sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20 sheet in my workbook and I want to copy fix range L3 to L7 to my MasterSheet. My source range from where I copy is same for all worksheet i.e. L3 to L7 but destination is b2 to f2, b3 to f3, b4 to f4 and so on.

Here is the code I wrote but I have to give dynamic destination range. 
So How should I do and apart from that.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To Worksheets.count
        Cells(x, 1).Value = Worksheets(x).Name
        Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("b2").Value = Worksheets(x).Name.Range("l3").Value
        Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("c2").Value = Worksheets(x).Name.Range("l4").Value
        Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("d2").Value = Worksheets(x).Name.Range("l5").Value
        Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("e2").Value = Worksheets(x).Name.Range("l6").Value
        Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("f2").Value = Worksheets(x).Name.Range("l7").Value
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Please more clearly define your inquiry.  It looks like you have code that works, and also that you have 20 sheets, some rangest that you copy, and this is the code you use.  "How should I do apart from that" is too broad, or would lead to subjective responses, which is inherently out of scope on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to move a row down for each successive sheet.

Something like this:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet, masterWS As Worksheet

    Set masterWS = Worksheets("MasterSheet")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "MasterSheet" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            masterWS.Range("A1").Offset(counter).Value = ws.Name
            masterWS.Range("B1:F1").Offset(counter).Value = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("L3:L7").Value)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```